# How can i pass video data in android using itents?

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Ok activity 1 displays thumbnails of videos from the SD card in a gridVideoView. I want to be able to click and pass the data onto activity 2 and play those videos. My book that i bought only shows me how to do this with strings. How can i do this so when i click a video in activity 1 it is passed and can be played in activity 2? If you would like the code I'll post it.

`Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class);
            intent.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID);
            startActivity(intent);`

```
       private VideoView video;
       private MediaController ctlr;
       File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
              "mnt/sdcard-ext");

      if (clip.exists()) {
      video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
      video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

       ctlr=new MediaController(this);
       ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
       video.setMediaController(ctlr);
       video.requestFocus();
       video.start();
      }
    }
 }
```

How do i do reference the intent in the VideoView?

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to simply pass the path of the video as a string to the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intentActionView = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentActionView.setDataAndType(pathToVideo, "video/*");
startActivity(intentActionView);
```